# Best practice for non-trivial data structures in typescript

Tags: typescript, performance, data-structures

I'm just getting started with `typescript`, and off-the-bat I've found that there aren't that many built-in data structures (doubly linked list, ordered dictionaries, queues, binary trees...).

I have found monorepos like [mnemonist](https://github.com/Yomguithereal/mnemonist) and [typescript-collections](https://github.com/basarat/typescript-collections) containing tested data structures. The first has more of a following, and the second is owned by the author of [typescript deep dive](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/), a highly recommended read.

However, both are yet to gain traction and show long-term maintenance.

Moreover, typescript's [roadmap](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) does not seem to incorporate these DSs in the visible future.

**Are there any currently recommended best practices pertaining to the use and maintenance of non-trivial data structures in typescript?**

(I'm getting the gist of where this is going, but I feel there's benefit in asking here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript is just JavaScript on steroids. The only things is does is

1. Allows you to use types to make your code more predictable and find errors
2. Transforms some modern JS features like `?.` and `??=` operators into old JavaScript that any browser can understand, basically the same thing babel does

TypeScript doesn't provide any objects that don't exist in JavaScript. `Map` exists in JS - `Map` exists in TS, `Set` exists in JS - `Set` exists in TS, but there is no objects that TS has but JS doesn't. And it will probably never contain anything like that, because adding new functionality is not the goal of this project, it's goal is to add *types* to reduce errors when writing code. All TypeScript type annotations get deleted after compilation, because browsers can't understand them.

Well, to be fair, TypeScript can in fact add some code to your project, namely, regenerator runtime that lets you use things, such as `async` functions, `for...of` loops and more, but this is just to make modern JS features work in browsers that don't understand them, this is not to provide any kind of new functionality.

If you want a data structure, that doesn't exist in JS, such as `LinkedList` or `Queue`, you either have to write them and type definitions for them yourself or install a package, like `mnemonist` you mentioned. It's perfectly fine to do the latter and you can go with it. `mnemonist` even provides type definitions (`.d.ts` files), so you don't have to worry about them. If a package doesn't have type definitions included out of the box (like `express`) you will usually install type definitions from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) (like `@types/express`). If type definitions haven't been written for the package you want, you will have to do it yourself. But this is not a problem in your case, you can just install `mnemonist` and go with it.